Log reader agent fails when replication filter is created using table from another database
I have a transactional replication setup on SQL Server 2019. I want to create a replication filter on one of the articles in which the filter clause needs to be specified using a table from another database in the same server.
So, my filter would be like
SELECT <published_columns> FROM [dbo].[PublishedTable] WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM AnotherDB.dbo.FilterTable)

Filter gets created successfully. But when I do an operation on publisher that satisfies the filter condition, log reader agent fails citing below error messages,
Error messages:
    The process could not execute 'sp_replcmds' on 'PublisherServer'. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL20011)
Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL20011
    Execution of filter stored procedure 1264423974 failed. See the SQL Server errorlog for more information. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 18764)
Get help: http://help/18764
    The Log-Scan Process failed to construct a replicated command from log sequence number (LSN) {<LSN>}. Back up the publication database and contact Customer Support Services. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 18805)
Get help: http://help/18805
    The statement has been terminated. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 3621)
Get help: http://help/3621
    The process could not execute 'sp_replcmds' on 'PublisherServer'. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL22037)
Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL22037

I understand that this is failing because the table used in replication filter belongs to a different database than the published database. I want to know why does it fail.
Also, I am looking for a possibility to fix this by granting any permissions.

My first instinct would be check the database permissions on that other database for your replication agent(s).

I did this check already. The account that runs the agent has access to the other database.

What kind of access?

It has sysadmin server role.
